# Dense sets in (0,1)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Let $E$ be the set of all $(x,y) \in [0,1] × [0,1]$ for which there exist $p \geq 2$ prime and $m, n \in N$ such that $(x, y) = (\frac{m}{p} , \frac{n}{p})$ and let $f : [0, 1] × [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$f(x,y)= 1$ if $(x,y)\in E$,
$f (x, y) := 0$ otherwise

Prove that both $E$ and $([0,1]×[0,1])\backslash E$ are dense in $[0,1]×[0,1]$ and deduce that $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

i know that a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is dense (in $X$) if every point $x$ in $X$ either belongs to $A$ or is a limit point of $A$ so in this case the closure of $E$ is constituting the whole set $[0, 1] × [0, 1]$ and how do i show that?

Comment: The set theory tag is not "for questions involving sets", much like your question undoubtedly involving numbers is not a number theory question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To show that a point is a limit point of the set $E$ you can construct a sequence of points in $E$ that converge to the point. So let $x \in [0,1]$ be given, for every $k$ let $p_k$ be a prime such that $p_k > k$. Then there exists an $m_k$ such that $|x - \frac{m_k}{p_k}| \le \frac{1}{p_k} < \frac{1}{k}$. Hence the sequence $\frac{m_k}{p_k}$ converges to $x$. Can you take it from here?

Edit: To prove that $([0,1]\times [0,1])\setminus E$ is also dense, I would argue by cardinality. The set $E$ is only countable. For any given point an arbitrarily small open neighborhood around it has uncountably many points. Hence there are points not in $E$ arbitrarily close to the given point, so the complement of $E$ is also dense.

Comment: for y i do the same thing and have convergence and that completes it?

Comment: @jamesblack For the set $E$ yes, then you still need its complement.

Comment: how would i find the copmlement, im not sure if i follow for the complement of a sequence

Comment: You can complete the proof for $E$ as you described but the problems says you should also prove that its complement $([0,1] \times [0,1]) \setminus E$ is dense.

Comment: right im just confused on how i would prove the complement is also dense; is there a shortcut based on what we derived above? or we have to construct a difference sequence

Comment: thank you for the edit! i think i get the idea but is there a way that i can write it more rigorously?